# Why does the temperature of the gas in a container moving with constant velocity does not change?

Tags: thermodynamics

> Systematic changes do not affect thermodynamic equilibrium.

What does this mean? And what kind of systematic changes are allowed?

The container with gas is stationary till some time then its given a constant velocity and the final temperature is asked , the answer says that systematic changes dont affect thermodynamic eqiulibrium and temperature remains constant .

Comment: What does your title have to do with your question? Maybe I just don't know what your title question is asking.

Comment: @DGS I suppose that the statement in the question is an example of a systematic change that does not affect thermodynamic equilibrium. In other words, the velocity of the container (systematic change) does not affect the temperature(thermodynamic equilibrium) of the gas .

Comment: I feel like there is an answer based on relative motion that I cannot quite grasp. Even though I voted to reopen this question, it may find a better home on Physics.SE.